# Сколько бы я (нe/ни) весила

Tags: орфография, частицы

Здравствуйте! Произошел спор с подругой, правильно ли написано предложение: "Сколько бы я ни весила, мои щеки всегда остаются при мне"?

Answer (score 2):

Да, все верно. Здесь усилительная частица "ни", отрицания быть не может.